I Need to match a line with or without and ending part
I'm trying to build a simple templating engine to learn how they work under the hood and I struggled with matching each section separately. I want the regex expression to be able to catch the section whether the @endsection is there or not.
No nested sections.
and for the section without @endsection I need to match it till the closing parentheses and get it in one line.
this is the html code :
@section('title','Home page')


@section('content')
    <h1>Home page<h1/>
@endsection

the output I want :
match 1 : @section('title','Home page')
match 2 : @section('content') Home page @endsection
Hope you understand what I want to achieve.

For clarity, please provide more test cases. Could the sections be nested? Also, for sections without an @endsection, is the selection ends before the next @section or just its own line?

No nested sections, I need the section without @endsection to end after the closing parentheses

Could @section\(.*?\)(?:(?:(?!@(?:end)?section\b)[\s\S])*@endsection)? this work?

Just match till double line break or @endsection: $regex = '~@section.*?(?:@endsection|\R{2})~s'. See PHP sample code.

Why not splitting: $sections = preg_split('~\s++(?=@section\b)~', $str);
